# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: should be calling method instead

Tags: javascript

I try to request an URL every 5 seconds. The following code is returning `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: validateUserTime`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ({
    validateUserTime: function() {
      return $.get('/myurl', function(data) {});
    }
  });
  return window.setInterval((function() {
    validateUserTime();
  }), 5000);
});
```

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong that is preventing a call to the method instead of doing it as a variable. Any idea?

Comment: You never define a variable `validateUserTime` anywhere. All you do is creating an object literal with one property but not assign it to anything. It just gets garbage-collected. Just define the variable properly: `var validateUserTime = function ...;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first statement, you are using an object literal without assigning it to anything.
Assign it to something to fix it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var functions = {
    validateUserTime: function() {
      return $.get('/myurl', function(data) {});
    }
  };
  return window.setInterval((function() {
    functions.validateUserTime();
  }), 5000);
});
```

Comment: Wondering how could I perform the get request first and then wait 5000 milliseconds. This example waits for the 5000 ms first and then makes the first request.

Answer (score 4):

This simply defines an anonymous object and throws it away:

```
({
  validateUserTime: function() {
    return $.get('/myurl', function(data) {});
  }
});
```

That doesn't define a `validateUserTime` function or method. You want something like this:

```
var validateUserTime = function() {
  return $.get('/myurl', function(data) {});
};
```

or perhaps:

```
function validateUserTime() {
  return $.get('/myurl', function(data) {});
}
```